# Passing variable to PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, devcon

I'm trying to pass a variable to this command in PowerShell

```
Start-Process $devconloc -ArgumentList "\disable" '"'$GPUList[1]'"' -ErrorAction Stop
```

`$GPUList[0]` is a hardware ID and needs to be passed to `devcon.exe` in quotes:

```
"PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1CBB&SUBSYS_087D1028&REV_A1\4&44A1B07&0&0008"
```

But I get the following error

> Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '"'.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: the `-ArgumentList` parameter requires a string or an _array_ of strings. you are not doing either since your items are delimited by a space. [*grin*]

Comment: Try `-ArgumentList 'disable', ('"{0}"' -f $GPUList[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others allready pointed out in the comments, there are two problems here:

1. You should pass a string-array to `-ArgumentList`. You do this by seperating you arguments with a `,`. Not a whitespace.
2. To fill in the object `$GPUList[1]` correct with your `"` around the string, there are two ways to fill the string with object:

   1. Escaping the `"` in the string with `` ` `` and phrasing the variables in `()` to make sure the array position will be taken in notice : `` -ArgumentList '\disable', `"$($GPUList[1])`" ``
   2. Filling in the variable with a position reference: `-ArgumentList 'disable', ('"{0}"' -f $GPUList[1])`